# jquery validate remote error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery.validate plugin for checking username availability

if user type `sample` i need to display error as

`sample is available` or `sample is not available`

```
$("#form_id").validate({
rules: {
username: {
required: true
}
},
messages:{
username: {
required: "username should not be blank",
remote: $('#username_id').val()+"is already available"
}
}
});
```

Remote error displays

```
is not available
```

i expect

```
sample is not available
```

---

**Updated:**
I had tried this

```
remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already available")
```

Once i click submit button error is displayed as `sample is not available` if i click submit again and again error becomes

```
server_pg.php is not available
```

**i dont know why jquery.validate misbehaving like this...**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any `remote` rule in your definition. Try:

```
$("#form_id").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            remote: 'test.cgi'
        }
    },
    messages:{
        username: {
            required: 'username should not be blank',
            remote: $.format('{0} is already available')
        }
    }
});
```

Also make sure that your server side script returns JSON content type with `true` or `false` value. Finally make sure that the username input has `id="username_id"` as specified in the messages.

Comment: This won't work, notice that you're getting the `.val()` to use in the error message *when the page loads* rather than when validation runs, that's the issue here :)

Comment: i had used remote in text element as remote="server_pg.php". i tried as ur code. Nothing works for me

Comment: @Mohan, please see my if update with `$.format('{0} is already available')` works for you.

Comment: @Darin - not my downvote but you're *still* missing the question, he wants to change the message depending on the response.

Comment: @Nick, yes indeed that seems to be the case.

Comment: @Darin i had updated my question your code is misbehaving for me. show with working example

Comment: @Mohan, not sure if it works but how about: `remote: function() { return $('#username_id').val() + ' is already available'; }`?

Comment: @Darin i think ur answer is very correct but not works for me. see my updated code

Comment: What is the response from the server? as in [the Milk](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/) example, @Darin's code should work just fine...please note that you need to return `echo "true";` or `echo "false";` and not a Boolean result!

Answer (score 2):

If you just remove this from messages:

```
remote: $('#username_id').val()+"is already available"
```

Then anything *but* `true` will be displayed as the message, so just have your server return *exactly*:

```
"nameChecked is already avaialable"
```

Return only this (or whatever message), quotes included and that string gets displayed.  This also ensures you're getting what was checked, not the current value.

Comment: @Mohan - I'm not sure how with the ajax bit, all you need to do is return from your remote page the error string with quotes and remove the `remote:` key from messages (still including wherever you're already adding the `remote` rule...since you seem to be getting the messages).